# Insert into a database a single string value of a randomized array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this code:

```
    $possible_pics = array(
        'red-pfp' => 'teem-pfp-red.svg',
        'pink-pfp' => 'teem-pfp-pink.svg',
        'blue-pfp' => 'teem-pfp-blue.svg',
        'green-pfp' => 'teem-pfp-green.svg',
        'purple-pfp' => 'teem-pfp-purple.svg',
        'yellow-pfp' => 'teem-pfp-yellow.svg',
        'orange-pfp' => 'teem-pfp-orange.svg',
    );
    shuffle($possible_pics);
    echo reset($possible_pics);
```

The result of it, I want to insert it into a database this way:

```
    $sentence = $connection->prepare("
        INSERT INTO users (id, user, pass, email, profile_pic) VALUES (:id, :user, :password, :email, :profile_pic)
    ");
    $sentence->execute(array(
        ':id' => $user_id,
        ':user' => $user,
        ':password' => $password,
        ':email' => $email,
        ':profile_pic' => $possible_pics
    ));
```

At this point I have already connected to the database, I'm just doing the SQL code.
As you can see, I am inserting the values into the database through an array, and in the part of `:profile_pic`, I am saying that I want to insert the result of the first code I added to my question, where I am shuffling the array and it only brings us 1 value. The problem here is that when I run this, it shows this:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion on line 73
```

Why is this happening and how can I make so it inserts the value of the randomized array? Where I do that, it works perfectly, and it returns effectively only 1 value. I can't do an `implode()` because it marks, `unexpected implode()`.

In resume, how can I insert into a database the returned value of the randomized array I showed at the beginning of my question?

Comment: Have you tried `':profile_pic' => reset($possible_pics)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick the output of `reset` function to a variable and use it in your `insert` statement.

```
shuffle($possible_pics);
$shuffledPic = reset($possible_pics);

...
$sentence->execute(array(
        ':id' => $user_id,
        ':user' => $user,
        ':password' => $password,
        ':email' => $email,
        ':profile_pic' => $shuffledPic 
    ));
```